# React app doesn't receive environment variables defined in Kubernetes pod

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes

The app is pretty simple: its job is to display three types of variables:

1. A variable defined locally in the code,
2. An environment variable defined in `Dockerfile` and overwritten on pod creation,
3. An environment variable defined only on pod creation.

The code is as follows:

```js
import './App.css';

function App() {
  let something = "3Wzc3mgdlIFwc4"
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
            <code>ENV1: </code> <em>{process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_VARIABLE}</em>
        </p>
        <p>
            <code>ENV2: </code> <em>{process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_VARIABLE_TWO}</em>
        </p>
        <p>
            Hash: <code>{something || "not set"}</code>
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`Dockerfile` used when building an image got the following values:

```
FROM node:17.1.0-buster-slim as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm install -g npm@8.1.3
RUN npm install --force
RUN npm install react-scripts@4.0.3 -g

COPY . ./
RUN chown -R node /app/node_modules

ENV REACT_APP_ENV_VARIABLE "It works!"

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.21.4-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

As I want to deploy the app on Kubernetes, the following pod and service are defined:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: playground-pod
  labels:
    name: playground-pod
    app: playground-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: playground
    image: localhost:5000/playground:1.0
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    env:
    - name: REACT_APP_ENV_VARIABLE
      value: "Variable from Kube!"
    - name: REACT_APP_ENV_VARIABLE_TWO
      value: "192.168.0.120"
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: playground-service
  labels:
    name: playground-service
    app: playground-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30003
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: playground-pod
    app: playground-app
```

After successful creation of the pod and the service, the variables in the pod container look this way:

```
/ # printenv | grep REACT_APP
REACT_APP_ENV_VARIABLE=Variable from Kube!
REACT_APP_ENV_VARIABLE_TWO=192.168.0.120
```

Yet, when I display the page in the browser, I can see something like this:

```
ENV1: It works!

ENV2:

Hash: 3Wzc3mgdlIFwc4
```

So, as you see, the local variable is displayed as expected, the variable that was intended to be overwritten is not overwritten and keeps the value from the `Dockerfile`, and the second variable that was only present in pod definition is not displayed at all.

Why is that? What should I do to make it work as expected?

Comment: React environment variables are a bit special in that they're injected into the code at build time. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: docker env variables exist server side and react is on the client.  You could write a simple API to expose them

Comment: HansKilian: thank you for the link! @Vorsprung: thanks for pointing this out! Would you recommend any reliable source showing how to do it?